# Convert modulus + exponent to PublicKey

Tags: java, kotlin, rsa

I have to connect to an API that is not-so-well documented and it seems its provider isn't very eager to update it. One of the endpoints is returning modulus/exponent for public key that is used to encrypt session password.

The format is like this:

```
"key" : {
  "modulus" : "udDX3BH5xUSmc94Q6aUlu2Z0i2Vi1gIGkeFW3B1c",
  "exponent" : "AQAB"
}
```

My attempt at obtaining PublicKey from it is:

```
fun toRsa() : PublicKey {
    val modulusBytes = Base64.decode(modulus, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val exponentBytes = Base64.decode(exponent, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val e = BigInteger(1, exponentBytes)
    val m = BigInteger(1, modulusBytes)

    val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e)
    val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    return factory.generatePublic(spec)
}
```

Unfortunately above method doesn't return a key this API expects. Any other idea for decoding this modulus/exponent? Would it be easier to get a PublicKey from BASE64_PEM (as this is alternative to modulus/exponent)?

Comment: I believe without documentation/specification of the API this will involve a lot of trial and error. It's essentially impossible to know what is needed and  testing it is not possible for us without access to the actual API.

Comment: Not a lot of information here. What's wrong the key returned by `toRsa()`?

Comment: When encrypting data with it (some password + session id) the request is not accepted by the server.

Comment: What error message do you receive on/from the server? By the way, I assume the modulus in your code is just a placeholder because it's clearly not a valid RSA modulus.

Comment: The server just gives "500". While trying various conversion methods on the web all I know thic c# is able to convert mod/exp to pem that is alternatively returned by this api: https://gist.github.com/misaxi/4642030 And yes - I know the modulus is truncated.